# JS filter or find an element in array where owner_name matches in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have got the two following arrays.

```
producers = { owner_name: "testing123, url: "http://test.com/", logo_svg: "http://test.com/logo.svg"}, { owner_name: "testing456, url: "http://test456.com/", logo_svg: "http://test456.com/logo.svg"}
result = { owner_name: "testing123, true, false}
```

I am trying to find a way to extract the logo_svg url from producers array when the `owner_name` match. I am very new to JS, so I'm not very good at it.

I manage to put this together but unclear on how I can get the logo_svg from that.

```
image={producers.filter((producer) => producer.owner_name === result.owner_name)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `image = producers.find(p => p.owner_name == result.owner_name).logo_svg`

but bear in mind that if the owner name does not exist in producers then `find` returns `undefined` and so you'll get an error so you can make the whole expression more robust by doing

```
obj = producers.find(p => p.owner_name === result.owner_name)
obj_url = obj ? obj.logo_svg || 'default_url_location'
image = obj_url
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), filter produces an array, so that is why you cannot get a valid variable inside your image.

You can try something like:

```
image={producers[producers.findIndex(el => el.owner_name === result.owner_name)]}
```

This will find the index of the item you are looking for and pass it immediately as the index in the producers array.